# SonarQube Azure Devops Not Authorized

Tags: sonarqube, azure-devops

I try to setup SonarQubein Azure DevOps. For that, I added the Prepare Analysis task and connected it via a token to my account. After the build, I have the Run Code Analysis I have the Code Analysis Tasks. But they throw the following error:

> ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
>
> ERROR: You're not authorized to run analysis. Please contact the project administrator.
>
> ERROR:

When I execute it with the same token on my local computer it works as expected and the data is uploaded.

My Configuration:

[image]

`moneyfox` is the Organization Key. I also tried the project_key. But that lead to issues with loading components.

[image]

Edit: when I use the Project key ("MoneyFox_MoneyFox"), I get this error in the Run Code Analysis Task:

[image]

Do I have to set something on the page that I can execute in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 0):

It should be project key, It works correctly on my side.

[image]

Build pipeline config

[image]

Test result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does the actual analyze task work as well? since for me it fails there.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/sonarqube/) guide to setup SonarQube with Azure DevOps.